# The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer

Tags: macos, mac

I have transcend 2TB portable harddrive; I suddenly get following error
`The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer`

Disk info is as follow

```
Name :  StoreJet Transcend Media
Type :  Disk

Partition Map Scheme :  Unformatted
Disk Identifier :       disk2
Media Name :    StoreJet Transcend Media
Media Type :    Generic
Connection Bus :    USB
USB Serial Number :     00000000000000000000
Device Tree :   IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/XHC1@14
Writable :  Yes
Ejectable :     Yes
Location :  External
Total Capacity :    0 Bytes
Disk Number :   2
Partition Number :  0
S.M.A.R.T. Status :     Not Supported
```

When I run `diskutil list` got following info

`/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 E0C861D2-CB67-479C-A998-C8EDD33DC407
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *0 B        disk2`

where `/dev/disk2` is my 2TB drive.  Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: It says unformatted, which means you should format it.

Comment: please see the size it is `*0 B` it is not showing the complete disk size

Comment: It looks to me like the drive has failed -- maybe the drive itself, maybe just its USB interface. Do you have a backup of what was on it?

Comment: Have you tried connect it to a different computer?

Comment: yes getting `cyclic redundancy check` in windows

Comment: Windows wouldn't be able to read it natively, as it's HFS+. Try it in another Mac & another enclosure. You'd need to mount it internally to be able to test the SMART status, as it's not supported over USB. Sounds like it died, anyway. Hope you have a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't written data to it before, try formating the disk. When you format the hard drive, it should work for you.

Comment: i had already written lot of data; it just stop working suddenly; also it i am not able to formate it because it is showing disk size is `*0 B`